# Remove sublist from list of dic

Tags: python, list, nested

I have these two lists and I would like to remove those elements already processes from total list.

```
processed = ['a','b','c']

total = [(1, 'a', 'alaksdl'),
         (2, 'x', 'asda'),
         (3, 'b', 'asda'),
         (4, 'c', 'wef'),
         (5, 'e', 'asaaa'),         
         (5, 'j', 'asd')                     
]
```

So, my final desired output would be:

```
total = [(2, 'x', 'asda'),(5, 'e', 'asaaa'),(5, 'j', 'asd')]
```

Comment: What have you tried yourself? What problems did you run into? Can you share the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use list comprehension and make sure `x[1]` will not in `processed` list.

```
[x for x in total if x[1] not in processed]
```